# Burnside's Lemma on octagon, using one of two colors on each side

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I am trying to find why the number of colorings of a regular octagon there are such that each side is colored either red or blue is 10. As well as this condition, each color must be used once. Essentially, out of the 8 edges, 4 are red and 4 are blue. If an octagon can be rotated to become another octagon, then they are considered the same.

My work on this is such: there are ${8 \choose 4} = 70$ possible combinations, forgetting about rotation. If a possible octagon is rotated clockwise once, there is no way it can be considered the same. If it is rotated twice, there are two ways it can be considered the same - a RBRBRBRB or BRBRBRBR color scheme. Similarly, if it is rotated $3$, $5$, or $7$ times, there are $0$ "fixed" combinations. If it is rotated $4$ or $6$ times, there are $2$ fixed points. The answer should then be $\frac{70+0+2+0+2+0+2+0}{8} = 9.5$. However, this is obviously not right, being a non-integer. The correct answer is $10$, found through writing a quick computer program.

Can anyone help me find where I messed up?

Comment: Is it part of the problem to use each color *precisely* $4$ times, or is that an incorrect deduction you made from the preceding requirements?

Comment: Also, if it is rotated $4$ times then there are $6$ fixed points. And you forgot to count the fixed points of reflections if you allow them.

Comment: Each color is used 4 times. No reflections are allowed.

Comment: I think you caught my mistake - there are more fixed points if it is rotated $4$ times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the octogon is rotated $4$ times, i.e. a half-turn, then there are precisely $\binom{4}{2}=6$ fixed points; every edge must have the same color as the opposing edge, dividing the edges into four pairs, two of which are blue and two of which are red.

Answer (score 1):

We may apply PET here since we require the cycle index $Z(C_8)$ of the
cyclic group $C_8$ anyway in order to apply Burnside. We have

$$Z(C_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) a_d^{n/d}$$

With $n=8$ this works out to

$$Z(C_8) = \frac{1}{8} a_1^8 + \frac{1}{8} a_2^4
+ \frac{1}{4} a_4^2 + \frac{1}{2} a_8.$$

We get

$$[R^4 B^4] Z(C_8; R+B) \\ =
\frac{1}{8} [R^4 B^4] (R+B)^8
+ \frac{1}{8} [R^4 B^4] (R^2+B^2)^4
+ \frac{1}{4} [R^4 B^4] (R^4+B^4)^2
\\ + \frac{1}{2} [R^4 B^4] (R^8+B^8)
\\ = \frac{1}{8} {8\choose 4}
+ \frac{1}{8} [R^2 B^2] (R+B)^4
+ \frac{1}{4} [R B] (R+B)^2
\\ = \frac{1}{8} {8\choose 4} + \frac{1}{8} {4\choose 2}
+ \frac{1}{4} {2\choose 1}
= \frac{35}{4} + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2} = 10.$$